# is there a way to fix device unauthorized without booting in to the os?

Tags: android, adb

I'm new to this community,

i can't booting in to the os because i put the wrong vb_meta,

I have already tried
`adb kill-server`
unplug the cable and plug it in again
but still not working

or is there a way to bypass the veriy boot check?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit strange: if your phone does not boot because of verified butt prevents it, I don't see the point where adb comes in. Adb is only available in a fully booted os or in some recovery ROMs (some with full adb access, some only adb side-load). But if your phone is not booting up it is not in a state where adb should be active.